# Inheritance as a way of adding modular abilities

Tags: c#, inheritance, scalability

I'm planning on creating a simple bot, but don't want to redo it once, and if it gets more complex in the future. So I'm wondering here if my approach will cause any issues in the future. And if there is a better solution/approach.

What am I planning to do:

- Have a `Communicator` class that reads user input
- Have an `Ability` class that has the basic methods for receiving a message and replying to the message
- Inherit that `Ability` class with all the other ability classes
- Store all the `Ability` classes in an array/list in main `Communicator` class
- When `Communicator` receives a message it sends it to all classes in that list and the class that the command was meant for replies (sends a message back) by calling a method in the `Communicator` class.

Example:

- Classes that inherit Ability: `Greet` and `Backflip`
- User input: **"Do a backflip"**
- "Do a backflip" is sent to classes Greet and Backflip.
- Both of the classes process the string
- Class Backflip detects a backflip command and replies with **"Backflip"**

How well can this kind of a solution scale? Also one of the main goals is to make it easy for others to implement their own Abilities and include them in the program, similar to [Hubot](https://hubot.github.com/).

Comment: If you are going to associate an `Ability` with a verb or phrase, then you might consider having a dictionary or similar storing the `Ability` object(s) that can handle each particular verb/phrase.  Also, for extensibility purposes, it would be better not to hard code the list of `Ability` objects, but rather have some mechanism that configures them at runtime, so that you can add further abilities in the future without having to touch your `Communicator` class.

Comment: What kind of automatic mechanism would you suggest to be used here?

Comment: At a minimum, use inversion of control on `Communicator` so that it isn't aware of `Ability` implementations.  Your program sets them up in code.  Even though it's still hard-coded, you have achieved looser coupling that way.  If it needs to be more dynamic still, maybe it determines them at runtime via .config file.  Or via some sort of implementation of a plugin pattern.  But the main idea is that `Communicator` doesn't know which `Ability` classes are going to be used, it is told by your program elsewhere.

Comment: Sounds smart. Do you think this solution is scalable otherwise? Would you do it differently?

Comment: How complex does the language processing need to be?  I can see some potential need to have a parser in between that figures out the particular commands.  Realistically, does a `Backflip` Ability need to understand anything other than `Backflip` as the command?  It shouldn't be responsible for parsing the language (i.e. shouldn't need to know what `Do a` means).

Comment: I must admit backflip was kind of a bad example. I was thinking of having a custom variable per ability which tells it how many "commands" to expect in a string. Commands would be always in the beginning of the string. So for example if ability has a command count set to 3 and message is: "Bot greet me random words", bot gets following commands command[0] = bot, command[1] = greet, command[2] = me, and rest of the string it assumes to be useless.
All commands start with "bot".

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/109937/discussion-between-shard-and-stephen-vakil).

Comment: Sounds like a good use of the factory pattern... give me mouse, give me cat...

Answer (score 1):

Conceptually, what you're describing isn't much different than an MVC...where your `Ability` maps nicely to a controller and the reply maps to a view. You might even be able to co-opt an MVC framework like ASP.NET/MVC.

What's different about an MVC and what you're describing is that there's typically a router of some kind that routes incoming commands to the specific controllers rather than broadcasting the message to all controllers to decide if they can respond. The broadcasting your considering seems a bit overkill...in that every single `Ability` has to parse and decide to respond. That presents a scalability problem...especially of lots of conversations are going on at the same time.

Also, what happens if, once your world gets big and complex, multiple `Abilities` respond?

In an MVC, the router is responsible for mapping patterns in the input to pre-registered or, more likely, conventions-based actions in the controllers. The router would have heuristics (often first-found wins) for determining which controller to call. Frameworks usually have all sorts of ways of customizing the router.

Unless this is just a for-fun thing, and isn't going to be heavily taxed, you'd be well-served to investigate an MVC framework of some kind to do the dirty work for you.

Comment: I edited my question and added this bit: Also one of the main goals is to make it easy for others to implement their own Abilities and include them in the program. Would you still recommend MVC?

Comment: At least with ASP.NET MVC, making new controllers is a easy as falling off a log...and I've fallen off of logs. There's a lot of support in the community. I'd recommend checking out a tutorial. Look at http://asp.net and you'll find a lot of interesting info.

Comment: I'm little bit concerned because it says web framework, and I'm thinking of stand alone helper bot, similar to Hubot.

Comment: Gotcha... Whether you can use the product or not, you could still benefit from a little study of the MVC pattern. Start by just googlin' "MVC pattern" and it'll take you in interesting directions.